# Can you use the new Ionic Grid with Ionic v1?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Is it possible to use the Ionic Grid `<ion-grid>` ( http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/ ) using Ionic Framework version 1.x?  Requirements dictate that Ionic v2 cannot be used and the documentation does not seem to clearly indicate.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can use the ionic v.1 grid 
 https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/components/#grid